# How to add and retrieve metafields to order when adding new order via api

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopify

I am trying to add metafields to new order as follows:

```
{       "order": {
    "line_items": [
      {
        "title": "Test Order item 1",
        "price": 0.00,
        "grams": "1700",
        "quantity": 1,      "taxable": false
      }
    ],
    "metafield": {
    "namespace": "inventory",
    "key": "amazonOrderId",
    "value": 123456789,
    "value_type": "integer"   },
    "email": "rahul@testOrder.com",
    "total_tax": 0.00   } }
```

The order is being created on shopify admin panel but on retrieving same order metafields are not returned. I am not sure where to find added metafield, is it added or not. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: It's `metafields` and not `metafield`

Comment: @ HymnZ thanks for making me correct. I changed it to metafields. But how we can retrieve back the metafields for a this particular order. And how we can confirm if they are stored for this order.

Comment: @HymnZ it is metafiled as I found below.

Comment: if you are using `/metafileds.json` and POST/PUT it will be `metafield` but on any other url it is `metafields` . `/orders/<id>.json` will require `metafields`

Comment: @HymnZ thanks. It will help in future.. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found how to store and retrieve metafields for an order in Shopify..

we need to make a POST call to /admin/orders/{order_id}/metafields.json with following format:

```
{
      "metafield": {
    "namespace": "global",
    "key": "amazonID",
    "value": "dfsfsd",
    "value_type": "string"
      }  
}
```

and then to retrieve the metafields for that particular order we use following url:
/admin/orders/{order_id}/metafields.json

Reference: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield#create